# using returned value in function

Tags: python, return

As you will see in my code, I am attempting to call and use a returned wanted value:

```
import random
def generator(a,b,c):
    x = 1
    while x == 1:
        elem = random.choice([a,b,c])
        if elem is 0:
            x = 1
            print ('trying again')
        if elem is not 0:
            x += 1
            a = random.randint(1,elem)
            y = elem - a
            return y and elem
new_function(y)
```

The purpose of `def_generator` is to take 3 different integers, randomly choose an int that is not 0 using a simple loop.

After that randomly choose a single number with in a range, like mentioned above and reduce it from the elem.
So far so good.

What I cant figure out is how to apply my new and wanted result (`y`) to a new function. I tried returning y but how to I extract it. Whenever I try to use y again I get an `error :'undefined variable'`.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please fix you code indentation. `new_function` is not defined. Provide full code.

Comment: You `return` a value from a function, and then you assign it to a variable in the caller, e.g. `foo = generator()`. `foo` is now the `return`ed value of `generator`. Beyond that I have no idea what exactly you're asking.

Comment: Is it `new_function(generator(x,y,z))` what you are looking for?

Comment: Look up the `and` operator. It's not doing what you think it does. You can replace it with `,` to return a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

After defining your function, you can return your value:

`my_result = generator(a,b,c)`

then use it: `new_function(my_result)`